# Access Query for TopN by Group

Tags: ms-access

I've reviewed quite a bit of the sites (e.g. Allen Brown) for creating a query that produces top 5 (or N) values by group.  I think I am getting hung up on the creation of a subquery because I'm referencing a previous query not a table.

I have a query started which counts by month the number of PIs (qryPICountbyMonth).  Currently the below gives a data mismatch expression error:

```
SELECT qryPI.EventMonth, qryPI.PI_Issue, Count(qryPI.PI_Issue) AS
CountOfPI_Issue
FROM qryPI
GROUP BY qryPI.EventMonth, qryPI.PI_Issue
HAVING (((Count(qryPI.PI_Issue)) In (Select Top 5 [PI_Issue] From [qryPI]
Where [EventMonth]=[qryPI].[EventMonth] Order By [PI_Issue] Desc)))
ORDER BY qryPI.EventMonth DESC , Count(qryPI.PI_Issue) DESC;
```

It is built off a a separate query, qryPI

```
SELECT tblPI.EventDate, Format([EventDate],'yyyy-mm',1,1) AS EventMonth, tblPI.PI_Issue
FROM tblPI
WHERE (((tblPI.EventDate) >= #4/1/2016# And (tblPI.EventDate) <= #5/31/2016#))
GROUP BY tblPI.EventDate, Format([EventDate],'yyyy-mm',1,1), tblPI.PI_Issue;
```

I'm hoping to have it generate the top 5 counts of PI_Issue by EventMonth.  If I haven't provided enough info let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The problem (or at least a problem) is with `[EventMonth]=[qryPI].[EventMonth]`. Both your primary source and your lookup are called `qryPI`. You have to alias at least one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this:

```
HAVING (((Count(qryPI.PI_Issue)) In (Select Top 5 [PI_Issue] From [qryPI]
```

`count(field)` will return an integer, not the set of values you're counting

---

I thought you could specify `TopN` in an Access query (it's in the properties), but you have to specify an `order by` clause, so it knows how to determine the `TOP`.
Have you tried:

```
SELECT top 5 
tblPI.EventDate, Format([EventDate],'yyyy-mm',1,1) AS EventMonth, tblPI.PI_Issue
    FROM tblPI
    WHERE (((tblPI.EventDate) >= #4/1/2016# And (tblPI.EventDate) <= #5/31/2016#))
    GROUP BY tblPI.EventDate, Format([EventDate],'yyyy-mm',1,1), tblPI.PI_Issue
    order by PI_Issue
```

also not sure why you're using `GROUP BY` in your inner query as you're not returning any aggregate functions.  Do you just need `DISTINCT` instead?

try:

```
SELECT distinct top 5 
    tblPI.EventDate, Format([EventDate],'yyyy-mm',1,1) AS EventMonth, tblPI.PI_Issue
        FROM tblPI
        WHERE (((tblPI.EventDate) >= #4/1/2016# And (tblPI.EventDate) <= #5/31/2016#))
        order by PI_Issue
```

---

Actually, if I understand what you want, you need that `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT`, but you also need to return the `COUNT(*)`:

```
SELECT 
  Year([eventDate]) AS yr, 
  Month([eventDate]) AS mo, 
  tblPI.PI_issue, 
  Min(tblPI.eventDate) AS MinOfeventDate, 
  Max(tblPI.eventDate) AS MaxOfeventDate, 
  Count(tblPI.PI_issue) AS CountOfPI_issue
FROM tblPI
WHERE 
  (((tblPI.EventDate)>=#4/1/2016# And 
  (tblPI.EventDate)<#6/1/2016#))
GROUP BY 
  Year([eventDate]), 
  Month([eventDate]), 
  tblPI.PI_issue;
```

then you want to apply the `TOPN` function to cnt_issue in an outer query:

```
SELECT TOP 5 from qryInner 
order by cnt_issue desc
```

except that `TOP5` applies to all the query results, not the results grouped by yy/mm, which is what I'm assuming you want, so try this:

```
SELECT TOP 5 
qry_inner.yr, 
qry_inner.mo, 
qry_inner.CountOfPI_issue, 
qry_inner.PI_issue, 
qry_inner.MinOfeventDate, 
qry_inner.MaxOfeventDate
    FROM qry_inner
    ORDER BY qry_inner.CountOfPI_issue DESC;
```

---

As far as I know, Access doesn't allow you to select the top number of rows within a group, so you'll need to limit your outer query results to one month, then apply the `TOP` function.

Comment: Point taken - still very novice at this and most has been learned by trial and error and this board.  Any thoughts on how to adjust would be hugely helpful.

Comment: Thanks Beth - excuse my ignorance but should I just a create different query and paste this in?  I am getting a 'does not include specified expression 'year(EventDate)' as part of an aggregate function when I do that.

Comment: @DChantal, try the updated SQL.  I created your table and some rows to confirm the syntax.

Comment: Maybe I can step back a bit here - my initial query does the count and gives:

Comment: Will do - Thanks Beth.  Was about to type the table I current have in place.

Comment: I gave it a shot and I think it is close.  In the original it would give three columns sorted by month/year, the description of the PI (text), and the total count for the month/year based on event date.  The problem is each month may have 50+ different entries in the text.  I was looking to limit it to the top 5 counts of each month instead:  'SELECT qryPI.EventMonth, qryPI.PI_Issue, Count(qryPI.PI_Issue) AS CountOfPI_Issue
FROM qryPI
GROUP BY qryPI.EventMonth, qryPI.PI_Issue
ORDER BY qryPI.EventMonth DESC , Count(qryPI.PI_Issue) DESC;'

Comment: Maybe to make it more straight forward - the exact code you have gives me the top 5 overall but I would need the top 5 for each year and month- so 5 lines for 4-2016 and 5 lines for 5-2016.  Thanks for the tremendous help